# C# Avalonia UI - Unable to Resolve Namespace

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, avaloniaui

I try to create the sample project from https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/next/tutorials/todo-list-app/. I created the project and added a new User Control as said in the tutorial.

I get following error:  "Unable to resolve type ToDoListView from namespace clr-namespace:ToDoList.Views Line 16, position 3.   ToDoList    E:\dev\csharp\ToDoList\ToDoList\Views\MainWindow.axaml  16  "

Following exactly the steps from the tutorial, i recognized one difference:
My Code has:  x:Class="ToDoList.ToDoListView"> instead of x:Class="ToDoList.Views.ToDoListView">

[image: MainWindow.axaml]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think the ToDoListView's x:Class should be:

```
x:Class="ToDoList.Views.ToDoListView"
```

check the codebehind's namespace too, it must match with the axaml x:Class "namespace"

and maybe you can try in the MainWindow use the using. This works also when the namespace is in other assembly.

```
xmlns:views="using:ToDoList.Views"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is was a error on creation.

x:Class="ToDoList.Views.ToDoListView" is now there after i recreate the project.